# Does Firefox support one-way sync?

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

I use Firefox on several personal computers and an Android phone, and I use Firefox sync to sync my personal bookmarks, passwords and browsing history between the computers.

I also use Firefox at work. I would like my to sync my work bookmarks and browsing history from my work computer to my personal computer, but I do not want the personal data to be synced back to my work computer and I would like to maintain this professional separation.

Does Firefox support one-way sync?

Answer (score 0):

[XMarks](https://www.xmarks.com/) is a Firefox add-on that gives you control on which bookmarks to sync on the computer profiles of your choice.

From their website: "Install Xmarks on each computer you use, and it seamlessly integrates with your web browser and keeps your bookmarks safely backed up and in sync.

Xmarks will sync across browsers too. Today we support Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Safari (Mac OS)."